# Loading simple jqPlot with jQuery Mobile and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I'm trying to put a simple jqPlot on my rails app, but I can't get it to load.. here's what's in my view:

```
<div id='chart1' style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>

<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
      var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});
</script>
```

When I open the page, the jQuery Mobile spinner goes on forever and I get this error in the JavaScript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)}
>   has no method 'jqplot'

I've added the appropriate jqPlot javascript files to my vendor/assets folder and referenced them in my application.js, so I don't think that's the problem.

Interestingly (or maybe not), if I add the line

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

at the beginning of the JavaScript block, then I get no error and the page loads fine, but with no jqPlot.. however, I'm then able to reference jqPlot from the JavaScript console.

I'm pretty new to web development, so I'm probably missing something basic.. any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show as your page example. This error states that jqPlot function don't exist and that means that it is jqPlot js file is probably not initialized (or inncorectly initialized). I can tell you that you dont need jQuery.noConflict();, jqPlot works just fine with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Well I have the jquery.jqplot.min.js file in my vendor/assets/javascripts folder and I reference it in my application.js with `//= require jquery.jqplot.min.js`.. I do the same thing with the jqPlot .css file. Is there another way I should be initializing it, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Oh you are using require, this could be a problem. Because it is using a async js loading, maybe jqplot is initialized after the pageinit event. Try with pageshow event.

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks! I still get the same error if I take out `jQuery.noConflict();` though, no idea why that could be.

Comment: That's because require is a scourge to jQuery and it plugins. While good on paper it's concept is sometimes unusable/problematic in a real life. This is not me throwing stick and stones on require.js but somethings should not be used together. You will learn that if you ever use require + jQuery Mobile + Phonegap :)

Comment: So what would be the best way to import jQuery and its plugins in rails?

Comment: Leave it as it is, just watch for this problem in the future. I would advised you to use pageshow no matter what because jqPlot works correctly only in that event.

Comment: @Gajotres: Can't say about Phonegap, but requireJs + JQM is working fine for me.

Comment: @jmellman - I set up require, JQM and jqPlot in a current demo site I'm doing ([here](http://www.iaasadvisor.com/) - click on compare, then pick visualize bottom left select menu on the table to load the data as plot). I'm loading jqPlot as a module, which works just fine. See answer below.

Comment: @frequent: Phonegap is main problem here. It will load jQM slower then usual and if require.js is not configured properly Phonegap will, for a brief moment show full html content before jQM styles are applied.

Comment: @Gajotres: I see. But I think you always have a Fouc when using requireJs, PhoneGap or not. I started to write [splashview](https://github.com/frequent/splashview) for that, which is like a startup screen hiding page contents while requireJs pulls everything together (repo needs to be updated :-)

Comment: Tnx for the info, I will take a look at it. I have a solution for this problem but I personally don't like it. :)

Comment: @Gajotres: if you need a splashview version running from inside requireJs, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have a `plot` module (file `jqplot.module.js`), which looks like this:

```
define([
      '../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot'
    , 'css!../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot'
],
function () {
    var plot;
    require([
        '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer'
      , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer'
      , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer'
      , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer'
      , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer'
      , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels'
      , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer'
      ],
    function () {
        plot = $.jqplot;
    });
    return plot;
  }
);
```

I call it on the page in question like this:

```
require(['plot'],
    function () {
    // in here I have $.jqplot available
    }
);
```

Inside my `main.js` I'm declaring the path to `jqplot.module`

```
plot:'../js/plugins/jqplot/jqplot.module'
```

Works fine for me.